# JDBC or Hibernate performance on a select query from a single table

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I need to fetch records from a read only table based on user input. The number of requests from users to retrieve these records is approximately 50,000 - 60,000 per hour and table has millions of records.

I considered using plain JDBC but people suggested using Hibernate as it optimizes query for better performance. By using Hibernate over JDBC, am I going to get better performance?

I thought using an ORM solution is unnecessary here since it is just a single read only table. But if it is going to help with performance which is what I want, I would sure go for it. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can tune query passed to JDBC for better performance, So performance wise, i think, both are same. Hibernate provide some more options like `caching`,`transaction mgmt` etc. But looking into your scenario, you can use JDBC & achieve good performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you can do it wrong with JDBC or JPA, and if you do it right there is not a big difference between both (if you are fine with raw resultset it might be marginally faster with JDBC, but then again if you need to map it to result objects JPA might be more mature). I your particular situation (large table, many results) caching benefits of JPA might be less relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC will always give better performance as compared to Hibernate for most of the database vendors. You can check the comparison made as given in the link below. He concludes that hibernate is fast when querying tables with less rows else jdbc is way better.

http://phpdao.com/hibernate_vs_jdbc/

The choice of hibernate over jdbc and SQL queries is not because of the performance but because of reasons mainly object persistence and database independence in terms of not writing database specific queries. You can read PDF guide to get a better view.

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/mindfire/Java_Hibernate_JDBC.pdf